# ExtJS: How do I load a ComboBox with the value in another ComboBox?

Tags: json, extjs, combobox

I'm a bit of an ExtJS noob.  I have a loaded up an ExtJS ComboBox (call it CBa) where the value field contains a JSON string that, when selected, should be loaded into a second combobox (CBb).

All of the examples I can find tell me how to load up a ComboBox from an external URL, but in this case, I want to load it up from a string I already have locally.

What magic do I place on each ComboBox to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a local combo like so :

```
// The data store containing the list of states
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
    data : [
        {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
        {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
        {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"}
        //...
    ]
});

var combo2 = Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox',{

   // combo config;
});
// Create the combo box, attached to the states data store
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
    store: states,
    queryMode: 'local', //makes it a local combo. Don't need a url.
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'abbr',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    listeners : {
          select : function() {
                var value = this.getValue();
                combo2.setValue(value);
          }
    }
});
```

Use the `select` event of `combo` to set the selected value into the second combo. Note that the selected value should be a value present in the `data` which is defined in the `store` of `combo2` for it to be set. Read docs of setValue [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-method-setValue) for exact information.

**EDIT after reading comment:**

You can set the second combo's store dynamically. Change the select event mentioned above to this:

```
select : function()
{
      var dataArray = [],data = this.getValue(); //Json string
      dataArray.push(Ext.decode(data)); //In case there is only one object in the string instead of any array.
      combo2.getStore().loadData(dataArray, false); //dataArray is automatically parsed into Model Objects. Second param to allow append to existing store data.
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful but doesn't get me all the way there.  The value of the first combo contains a json string that represents the values that should be in the second combo's store.  So it's not that I want to be able to set the value of the second combo, it's that I want to set the second combo's STORE.  Do I create a new store and tell the second combo to use it, or do I change the values in the second combo's store with my json string?  In either case, how do I manage this dynamic, yet local, store for the second combo?